# problem in using \usepackage{pgfplots} package

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, pgfplotstable, plot, latexmk

I think I have a problem with using `\usepackage{pgfplots}` package since when I compile any file latex using pgfplots, it fails with this error:

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.232 ...PÍN¢Ø(¥´„¢¶–€°Ý´¸â–ŠÁF=éqíKøP
                                                  KƒKŠ(˜÷§QŽ(Z 6š0iih ¢Š\qš...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.232 ...N¢Ø(¥´„¢¶–€°Ý´¸â–ŠÁF=éqíKøPKƒKŠ(
                                                  ˜÷§QŽ(Z 6š0iih ¢Š\qš J)vÑŠ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.232 ...´„¢¶–€°Ý´¸â–ŠÁF=éqíKøPKƒKŠ(˜÷§QŽ(Z 
                                                  6š0iih ¢Š\qš J)vÑŠ J]¦”
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.232 ...€°Ý´¸â–ŠÁF=éqíKøPKƒKŠ(˜÷§QŽ(Z 6š0iih 
                                                  ¢Š\qš J)vÑŠ J]¦”
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.232 ...–ŠÁF=éqíKøPKƒKŠ(˜÷§QŽ(Z 6š0iih ¢Š\qš 
                                                  J)vÑŠ J]¦”
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.232 ...éqíKøPKƒKŠ(˜÷§QŽ(Z 6š0iih ¢Š\qš J)vÑŠ 
                                                  J]¦”
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.233 \P
         všub€
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.233 \Pvšu
             b€
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 8ô¥
          J\{PF=éiq@ì7o½}éØ4m4‚ÂQNÛKŒPc)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº(Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.¨...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 8ô¥J\{P
               F=éiq@ì7o½}éØ4m4‚ÂQNÛKŒPc)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº(Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.¨...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 8ô¥J\{P
                F=éiq@ì7o½}éØ4m4‚ÂQNÛKŒPc)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº(Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.¨...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 8ô¥J\{PF=éiq@ì7o½
                           }éØ4m4‚ÂQNÛKŒPc)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº(Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.¨...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.234 8ô¥J\{PF=éiq@ì7o½}é
                             Ø4m4‚ÂQNÛKŒPc)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº(Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.¨...

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no é in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Ø in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ‚ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Â in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Û in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Œ in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 8ô¥J\{PF=éiq@ì7o½}éØ4m4‚ÂQNÛKŒP
                                          c)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº(Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.¨...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no š in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Þ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ô in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ¢ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ‹ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no  in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ” in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Û in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...iq@ì7o½}éØ4m4‚ÂQNÛKŒPc)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛE
                                                  hº(Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.¨mü~t¿….aò...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no º in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...ì7o½}éØ4m4‚ÂQNÛKŒPc)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº
                                                  (Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.¨mü~t¿….aò¢:\...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no Ý in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ¢ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no — in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...}éØ4m4‚ÂQNÛKŒPc)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº(Ý¢—
                                                  Ô»E.Ú.¨mü~t¿….aò¢:\vÚ]¢...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no Ô in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no » in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Ú in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...ÂQNÛKŒPc)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº(Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.
                                                  ¨mü~t¿….aò¢:\vÚ]¢Ž`åC6š\...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no ¨ in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...ÛKŒPc)všvÞô¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº(Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.¨m
                                                  ü~t¿….aò¢:\vÚ]¢Ž`åC6š\cÞ...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no ü in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ¿ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no … in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ò in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ¢ in font cmr10!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.234 ...¢‹”f)p)ÛEhº(Ý¢—Ô»E.Ú.¨mü~t¿….aò¢:\
                                                  vÚ]¢Ž`åC6š\cÞ´RÑÌChÛíN¢—...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no Ú in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ¢ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Ž in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no å in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no š in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Þ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no  in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ´ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Ñ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Ì in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...Ô»E.Ú.¨mü~t¿….aò¢:\vÚ]¢Ž`åC6š\cÞ´RÑÌ
                                                  ChÛíN¢—0Æí¥ÛN£mÀ7n:QƒëOÛI...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no Û in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no í in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ¢ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no — in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Æ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no í in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ¥ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Û in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no £ in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...aò¢:\vÚ]¢Ž`åC6š\cÞ´RÑÌChÛíN¢—0Æí¥ÛN£m
                                                  À7n:QƒëOÛIëK™€”S¶Ñ¶•Ø ƒFÚu...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no À in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ƒ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ë in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Û in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ë in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ™ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no € in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ” in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ¶ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Ñ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ¶ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no • in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Ø in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ƒ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Ú in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...ÛíN¢—0Æí¥ÛN£mÀ7n:QƒëOÛIëK™€”S¶Ñ¶•Ø ƒFÚu
                                                  îÍæ–Š.Eí´\ÑNÛFÑEÀL6...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no î in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...N¢—0Æí¥ÛN£mÀ7n:QƒëOÛIëK™€”S¶Ñ¶•Ø   ƒFÚuî
                                                  Íæ–Š.Eí´\ÑNÛFÑEÀL6Ó©...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...¢—0Æí¥ÛN£mÀ7n:QƒëOÛIëK™€”S¶Ñ¶•Ø    ƒFÚuî
                                                  Íæ–Š.Eí´\ÑNÛFÑEÀL6Ó©)...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no Í in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...0Æí¥ÛN£mÀ7n:QƒëOÛIëK™€”S¶Ñ¶•Ø  ƒFÚuîÍ
                                                  æ–Š.Eí´\ÑNÛFÑEÀL6Ó©) ›...
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no æ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no – in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Š in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...N£mÀ7n:QƒëOÛIëK™€”S¶Ñ¶•Ø   ƒFÚuîÍæ–Š.
                                                  Eí´\ÑNÛFÑEÀL6Ó©) ›hÅ:Š n
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...mÀ7n:QƒëOÛIëK™€”S¶Ñ¶•Ø ƒFÚuîÍæ–Š.E
                                                  í´\ÑNÛFÑEÀL6Ó©) ›hÅ:Š n
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no í in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ´ in font cmr10!
! Undefined control sequence.
l.234 ...n:QƒëOÛIëK™€”S¶Ñ¶•Ø    ƒFÚuîÍæ–Š.Eí´\
                                                  ÑNÛFÑEÀL6Ó©) ›hÅ:Š n
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Missing character: There is no Ñ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Û in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Ñ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no À in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...K™€”S¶Ñ¶•Ø ƒFÚuîÍæ–Š.Eí´\ÑNÛFÑEÀL
                                                  6Ó©) ›hÅ:Š n
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no Ó in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no © in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...¶Ñ¶•Ø  ƒFÚuîÍæ–Š.Eí´\ÑNÛFÑEÀL6Ó©) 
                                                  ›hÅ:Š n
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no › in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Å in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no Š in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.234 ...ƒFÚuîÍæ–Š.Eí´\ÑNÛFÑEÀL6Ó©) ›hÅ:Š 
                                                  n
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no Š in font cmr10!
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 235.

("C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omscmr.fd"
File: omscmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 235.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.235 :Š\P

A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.235 :Š\P

A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

Missing character: There is no ´ in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no š in font cmr10!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.236 Z]´cš
            %&ÓOÅ†•¦íÅIEaŠ´¸§Q@Xn
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.
```

Please how I can fix this error!!

Comment: Crystal balls are rare these days. So please provide some minimal document that illustrates the issue.

Comment: The message looks as though LaTeX is trying to read a binary file as a TeX file. Unfortunately, it is not quite clear from the message which file that is. Can you upload the whole `.log` file of  a minimal example document that reproduces the error to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/? Please also post the document code that reproduces the error for you (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Chances are a package update/installation went wrong. Did you install any package manually?

Comment: I failed with this error for any simple code for example: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}......just when I use the \usepackage{pgfplots}...

Comment: This suggests that your `pgfplots.sty` or another `pgfplots`-related file is corrupted or at least not what it claims to be. Usually this shouldn't happen. Did you install any package manually (i.e. by downloading it from CTAN or elsewhere yourself)? Type `kpsewhich pgfplots.sty` into your command line and have a look at the file that is indicated there. Does it look TeX-y when you open it? Can you show us the *full* `.log` file of the very small example from your last question (upload it to pastebin, see my comment above)?